# Modification of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

If I find out that a process $X_t$ has the same characteristic of a Brownian motion, namely: $B_0=0$ a.s., stationary and independent increment, $B_t-B_s$ is $N(0,t-s)$ and continuous sample path a.s.

1) Can I conclude that $X_t$ is a modification of the Brownian motion?

2) What if $X_t$ has all the property of the B.M. except a.s. continuous sample path?

If I can't conclude that is a modification (namely question 1) is false), how could I show that a process with that characteristic is a modification of a B.M.?

If this is a silly question please let me know anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1) It's the definition of a standard BM.

2) $(X_t)$ in this case is called a pre-Brownian Motion. There exists a modification of $(X_t)$ having continuous sample paths (e.g., Thereom 2 on page 14 [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/undergrad/projects-undergrad/Project08.pdf)).

Comment: so how could I show that a ($X_t$) pre-Brownian Motion  is a modification of a B.M.? If I show that it ($X_t$) has a modification with continuous sample paths, it means that ($X_t$) is a modification of a B.M.?

Comment: @Alias__, Yes. The notion of pre-Brownian motion depends only on the finite-dimensional distributions of the process, and any two modifications share the same finite-dimensional distributions. So, if $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a pre-Brownian motion and $Y=(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a modification of $X$ with continuous sample paths, then $Y$ is also a pre-Brownian motion and hence a Brownian motion.

Comment: @SangchulLee it seems me that you already answered affirmatively but I would like to be sure to have understood well. If I show that a pre-Brownian motion ($X_t$) has a modification with continuous sample paths ($B_t$), then P($X_t=B_t)=1$ for each t, namely $X_t$ is a modification of the Brownian motion $B_t$. is it right?

Comment: @Alias__, That seems correct. :)